# How To Calculate Source and Bits

Tags: data-communication

6 sources, 4-bit rate of 160 kbps, and 2-bit rate of 320 kbps are combined using multiple slot TDM with one synchronizing bit. Assuming 2 bits from the first are taken from 4 sources and 4 bits from the second are taken from 2 sources.

1. what is the size of a frame in bits?
2. what is the frame rate?
3. what is the duration of a frame?
4. what is the data rate? in Mbps.